# ASP.NET @User.Identity.Name returning a null value

Tags: asp.net, database, identity

I connected ASP.NET with ssms and have a database with tables Users, Roles, UserRoles and UploadedFiles. I am doing a task where a user has to subscribe (by pressing a button) in order for him to upload files. I am doing this by changing the ID of the RoleId of the logged in user to that of a subscribed user.

Now, to do this, I am using @User.Identity.Name to get the email of the currently logged in user and edit his roleID. However, the problem is that @User.Identity.Name is returning null. And what's worse is that before, I already had done a similar example where a user uploads a file and I get the email using @User.Identity.Name, and it worked. however this one does not.

This is the code that handles the Subscription in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Subscribe(string email)
    {
        UsersRepository ur = new UsersRepository();
        var user = ur.GetUser().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == email);
        user.Email = email;
        Role defaultRole = ur.GetDefaultRoleSubscribe();

        ur.AllocateRoleToUserSubscribe(user, defaultRole);

        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

The code inside the repository:

```
public void AllocateRoleToUserSubscribe(User u, Role r)
    {
        u.Roles.Add(r);
        Entity.SaveChanges();
    }
    public Role GetDefaultRoleSubscribe()
    {
        return Entity.Roles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Title == "Subscribed User");
    }
```

The code in the subscribe.cshtml:

```
<form method="post" action="\Users\Subscribe" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="hidden" value="@User.Identity.Name" name="email" />

    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should post the UsersRepository implementation with the GetUser method as well.

Comment: The thing is that I know the method works. I ran the same code but for a different task and it worked.. and I know all of my methods work because I use them elsewhere.. It's just with this one

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I'd like to see the code that works then.

Comment: I edited the post with the code that works. What it does basically upload an image and save it in the database. The mechanism is literally the same. I get the user with @User.Identity.Name and use his User instance.

Comment: So, first of all. It works because you are calling `<h1>@User.Identity.Name</h1>` inside your razor page. Because the user object is associated with the http request (It's inside HttpContext. Which is a hint). Now, the code that doesn't work, doesn't work because, when you create a new instance of UserRepository, you aren't using dependency injection. So, inside your UserRepository there won't be any User associated to the HttpContext. What you need to do is use dependency injection so that the UserRepo will have the same instance of the HttpContext where the User claim resides.

Comment: Feel free to repost it with more explanation than "code that works". A user should be able to read your question and understand it without having to look at the comments below the question: comments are to be treated as ephemeral.

Comment: Oh i would like to add something else Dennis.. For testing purposes, prior of all this, I tried using the literal same methods but instead of doing them in the Subscription.cshtml, I wrote them in a class List.cshtml, which uses a foreach to display all the users in the database.. The way I am displaying it is like this: 

@Html.ActionLink("Change Role", "Subscribe", new { Email = user.Email }, new { onclick = "return window.confirm('Are you sure?')", Style = "font-weight:bold;" })

Keep in mind that it uses the same methods, no changes whatsoever